# string.h file not found

Tags: c, linux, string, ubuntu

```
#include <string.h>
```

Clang doesn't find `string.h`.
Then I give it a better path but another file is not found:

```
[build] /usr/include/string.h:26:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
[build]  #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
[build]           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What should I do?

Can I just download `string.h` for my "llvm" environment and paste it there?:

```
/usr/include/llvm-10/llvm
```

[image: PHOTO OF THE ERROR]

Comment: clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

Comment: Maybe use your package manager to update llvm?

Comment: yeah maybe .....

Answer (score 1):

If you are on an ubuntu system and encounter such problems in the future, you can find the answer by typing this command:

```
apt-file search bits/libc-header-start.h
```

Then download the corresponding library file using `apt-get install xxx`. If it is a red hat system or other, there should be similar commands. 
[image]

Comment: thank you I will check it out now didnt see the answer before I typed my second message

Comment: udo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386-amd64-cross ........... but actually I donÄt know which package I should install. Can I install all packages?

Comment: apt-get install libc6-dev

Comment: Reading state information... Done
libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

Comment: until now it doesnt find my string.h xD

Comment: Still report the same error? Please show me the screenshot

Comment: hi I added a picture in the question :)

Comment: I've had a lot of luck by doing apt-get build-dep complier-I-want-to-use